# How to convert a json response to match schema (not manually)?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to validate a schema for complex JSON. We can easily compare a schema with API response by below command

```
And match response == response_SCHEMA
```

(where "response_SCHEMA" is json schema)

For small json we can manually create:
Actual API response:

```
{ "id": "123", "name": "abc", "type": "Mumbai", "owner": { "name": "Mr Singh", "type": "Business", "licenseNo": "ASL8989" }
```

Converted the response to below - manually

```
{ "id": "#number", "name": "#string", "type": "#string", "owner": { "name": "#string", "type": "#string", "licenseNo": "#string" }
```

How to create this kind of schema automatically for a complex big json having 300-400 lines? So, we can compare it with API response with Karate.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the schema design is that you can easily cut and paste an actual JSON and either use it as it is (data match, recommended) or edit it to use `#string` etc (schema match).

When you say 300-400 lines, most likely you mean an array of JSON. All you need to do is specify the schema of the "repeating part" and then use `match each`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-each

```
* def actual = [{ a: 1, b: 'x' }, { a: 2, b: 'y' }]
* def schema = { a: '#number', b: '#string' }
* match each actual == schema
```

The short answer is there is no automatic way to do it. Typically you never need to do more than a few lines. Maybe you can write your own custom utility.

Comment: Thanks Peter, appreciate your response.

When we do API automation with rest-assured then there are some online utilities which helps in directly getting the schema which we can compare with response eg below:

[link] https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter

But getting schema from these doesnt work with Karate so need your help

Comment: Are you suggesting there is no way for Karate, and we need to write custom utility. Please confirm.

Comment: @Mayank hey, if you are referring to Json-Schema you can use Java-interop, and the demos even has an example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/schema/schema.feature - just so you know, Karate's approach is far simpler: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/878984854012022784 - finally if you don't like Karate, please go ahead and use REST-assured :P

Comment: @Mayank and I have to say - validating against a Json schema is one of the most pointless things in API testing, just my opinion, and for why I think so, please read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/78#issuecomment-569292547

Answer (score 0):

@Mayank I also faced this issue, Unfortunately I didn't find any options.

So I created my own small JS to convert the actual JSON into JSON Schema which is compatible with Karate Fuzzy Match.

The output may look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vOO8.png)

Hope This Helps!...

```js
function main() {
  var json;
  if (document.getElementById('code').value) {
    try {
      json = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('code').value);
      document.getElementById('code').value = JSON.stringify(inputTxt, null, 2);
      document.getElementById('output').value = '';
    } catch (e) {
      document.getElementById('output').value = e;
    }
  }


  let outArr = {};
  let output = convertJson(json, 'response', true);
  ouput = Object.assign(output, outArr);
  Object.keys(ouput).forEach(key => ouput[key] === "#undefined" && delete ouput[key]);
  document.getElementById('output').value = JSON.stringify(output, null, 2);

  function convertJson(json, keyName, isParent) {
    let outA = {};
    let x = {};
    let y = {};
    Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key) {
      if (!(getJSType(json[key]) === "object") && !(getJSType(json[key]) === "array")) {
        x[key] = '#' + getJSType(json[key]);
      }
      if (getJSType(json[key]) === "object") {
        x[key] = convertJson(json[key], key, false);
      }
      if (getJSType(json[key]) === "array") {
        x[key] = '#' + getJSType(json[key]);
        // y[key + 'arr'] = getArray(json[key][0], key, false);
        getArray(json[key][0], key, false);
      }
    })

    if (isParent) {
      if (Object.keys(x).length > 0) {
        outA[keyName] = x;
      }
      if (Object.keys(y).length > 0) {
        outA[keyName + 'Arr'] = y;
      }
      return outA;
    } else {
      if (Object.keys(y).length > 0 && isParent) {
        return y;
      }
      if (Object.keys(x).length > 0) {
        return x;
      }
    }
  }

  function getArray(json, keyName, isParent) {
    let z = {};
    if (!(getJSType(json) === "object") && !(getJSType(json) === "array")) {
      z[keyName + 'Arr'] = '#' + getJSType(json);
    } else {
      z[keyName + 'Arr'] = convertJson(json, keyName, false);
    }
    outArr = Object.assign(outArr, z);
  }


  function getJSType(valToChk) {

    function isUndefined(valToChk) {
      return valToChk === undefined;
    }

    function isNull(valToChk) {
      return valToChk === null;
    }

    function isArray(valToChk) {
      return valToChk.constructor == Array;
    }

    function isBoolean(valToChk) {
      return valToChk.constructor == Boolean;
    }

    function isFunction(valToChk) {
      return valToChk.constructor == Function;
    }

    function isNumber(valToChk) {
      return valToChk.constructor == Number;
    }

    function isString(valToChk) {
      return valToChk.constructor == String;
    }

    function isObject(valToChk) {
      return valToChk.constructor == Object;
    }

    if (isUndefined(valToChk)) {
      return "undefined";
    }
    if (isNull(valToChk)) {
      return "null";
    }
    if (isArray(valToChk)) {
      return "array";
    }
    if (isBoolean(valToChk)) {
      return "boolean";
    }
    if (isFunction(valToChk)) {
      return "function";
    }
    if (isNumber(valToChk)) {
      return "number";
    }
    if (isString(valToChk)) {
      return "string";
    }
    if (isObject(valToChk)) {
      return "object";
    }

  }
}

function formatJson() {
  if (document.getElementById('code').value) {
    try {
      var inputTxt = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('code').value);
      document.getElementById('code').value = JSON.stringify(inputTxt, null, 2);
      document.getElementById('output').value = '';
    } catch (e) {
      document.getElementById('output').value = e;
    }
  }
}

function minifyJson() {
  if (document.getElementById('code').value) {
    try {
      var inputTxt = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('code').value);
      document.getElementById('code').value = JSON.stringify(inputTxt, null, null);
      document.getElementById('output').value = '';
    } catch (e) {
      document.getElementById('output').value = e;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript Code Runner</title>

</head>

<body>
  <h3>Generate the Json Schema for Response</h3>
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <textarea id="code" style="flex: 1; height: 80vh;" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
    <textarea id="output" style="flex: 1; height: 80vh; overflow: auto;" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex;height: 12;"></div>
  <button onclick="runCode()">Generate Schema</button>
  <button onclick="formatJson()">Format JSON</button>
  <button onclick="minifyJson()">Minify JSON</button>
  <script src="src/jsonconverter.js"></script>

  <script>
    function runCode() {
      main();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: another way is to integrate rest assured in same framework and utilize its for schema validation, we did this way in past.